# Setup a thirdparty dependency repository on Artifactory

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I'm quite new to the JFrog Artifactory, but here is my requirement : I want to resolve my compile dependencies using Artifactory and publish the built artifacts to the Artifactory. Now I use gradle for my build. Also going through the initial tutorial I'm able to publish my artifacts to the repository. However now I want to be able to compile my project using the Artifactory. My project has some thirdparty dependencies lets say commons-logging and antlr. The script that i have is as follows

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'http://localhostr:8081/artifactory'   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-dev-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
        defaults {
            publications ('mavenJava')
            publishPom = false
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-dev'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.web
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'antlr:antlr:2.7.6',
    'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1'
}
```

Now i want to know is how do I have these thirdparty dependecnies in my gradle-dev repository in the gradle format. Altogether my gradle projects use around 40-50 such thirdparties. Is there a simpler way to copy all these dependecnies to my Artifactory ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will want to setup a remote repository:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories